# Query a dataTable by large Query String

Tags: sql, string, text, datatable

I have a datatable that i want to query.
the query is very large and complicated and it works when i run it in the SQl Server Editor - so i have the query text.

i need to query the datatable with this query String.
To Translate the query into linq will take years, and also Select() method of DataTable won't handle it.

How can i operate a text query on a dataTable?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to go ahead and make it a stored procedure, especially if it takes in a relatively fixed set of parameters.  Then you can just add your stored procedure into your Linq2 (entitites, sql, whatever) command and map it to return the appropriate object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`SqlCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx), like this:

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
using(var command = new SqlCommand(@"
your very long query
    ", connection)
using(var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
    while(reader.Read()) {
        //use reader[colIndex] to get a field from the current row
    }
}
```

---

You can load it into a DataTable using a [`SqlDataAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx), like this:

```
var table = new DataTable();

using(var connection = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
using(var command = new SqlCommand(@"
your very long query
    ", connection)
using(var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command)) {
    adapter.Fill(table);
}
```